# Probability that empirical distribution does not equal probability mass function

Tags: probability

Consider $N$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ that take value in a finite set $\mathcal{X}$, such that $\mathbb{P}(X_i = x) = p(x)$. To avoid degeneracy, assume $p(x)$ is rational for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$.
Define the empirical distribution as
$$\mu^{N}(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{1}(X_i = x),$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function. Can we obtain a bound for the following probability in terms of $N$? Thanks!
$$\mathbb{P}(\mu^{N} \neq p) \stackrel{?}{\leq} g(N)$$

---

My attempt:
I can show that
$$\mathbb{E}[\Vert \mu^{N} - p\Vert_1]\leq |\mathcal{X}|\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}.$$
Then, by Markov inequality, for any $\epsilon > 0$, I have
$$\mathbb{P}(\Vert \mu^{N} - p\Vert_1 \geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{|\mathcal{X}|}{\epsilon}\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}.$$
Then, I am not sure how to get rid of the $\epsilon$ dependency...

Comment: I think your EDF needs to be normalized by $N$.

Comment: Also, what if all $p(x)$ are irrational? Then we know $\mu^N \neq p$ for all $x \in \chi$ and $N>0$

Comment: EDF updated. And good point, never thought about p(x) being irrational! Does that mean we cannot have a general bound?

Comment: You already have what I would consider a decent bound from your application of markov. The problem is that the event $\mu^N \neq p$ is too strict (as I pointed out above) or narrow. Generally, when you are defining probabilities for continuous things like probabilities, you need to use inequalities. Equality makes sense only for things that are constrained to a discrete set of choices.

Comment: Technically, for every N, we can explicitly compute the probability that $\mu^N = p$ if $p$ is rational. I wonder if there is a smart way to bound that.
But I do see jumps, for example if I set $p = [0.5,0.5]$, then for all odd $N$, the probability that $\mu^N = p$ will always be zero.

Comment: I think without additional restrictions on the distribution your result using Markov is about as good as I can see you getting the bound. I don't think the equality makes sense, buy your inequality does.